# PHP: pop show that app server time out

Tags: php, session-timeout

I have a PHP app written in codeIgniter.  Getting some complaints from clients about the app timing out.  Their session times out after two hours of inactivity and they can't seem to remember that.

Is there a way and if so, how, to show a pop up message when a users session has timed out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP` cannot display a pop up by itself, but you could probably have a `JavaScript` query the session status and display a pop up when the session is expired, or even better, count the time since the session opened and let the user know in advance that his session is about to time out

If you want change the duration of the session, see this line in your `config.php`

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

7200 is 120 minutes * 60 seconds. If you change it to `0`, the session will not expire.

To add a warning, the very simplest method would probably to add a `JavaScript` similar to

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Your session will expire in 5 minutes")},6900000); // 6900 seconds (115 minutes) * 1000 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using:

- Javascript function using timers (and show a popup after a period of time)
- In PHP using a timer set in your `$_SESSION` and calculate the difference in timestamps  (when the user is redirected to a login page, pass a message "Your session has timed out")
- A hard-timeout/page redirect using a meta equiv tag to a session-timeout page.

You can even go as far as offering different timeout periods for different user groups...

An example using PHP, which logs them out, tells them and redirects once they log back in:

```
// get time now
   $now = time();

// Set session period
   $autologout = '7200';

if (isset($_SESSION["TimeOut"]))
{   
    if ($now > $_SESSION["TimeOut"])
    {
    // Unregister session and set message
        session_unregister("authenticatedUser");
        session_register("loginMessage");
        $loginMessage = "Your session has timed out";

    // Capture request URL and store in a cookie so that they 
    // are logged back into the page they were requesting
        $requestURL = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
        setcookie("requestURL",$requestURL,"0",'/','',FALSE,TRUE);

    // Redirect back to login page
        header("Location: " . $loginScript);
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['TimeOut'] = ($now + $autologout);
    }
} else {
        $_SESSION['TimeOut'] = ($now + $autologout);
}
```

This presumes that your system session timeouts are longer or set otherwise. It's not written for codeIgnitor either, but hopefully helpful to understand what can be done to soften the blow of session expiry.

Comment: Thanks for this Nickhar.  Another suggestion from above looks to work better for our client, but I am interested in this on for a couple of other applications I am working on  - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Probarly your session maxlifetime is 2 hours.
You can edit that with this: (replace 8 with the max lifetime in hours).

```
 ini_set(’session.gc_maxlifetime’, 8*60*60);
```